# Cannot convert between std::chrono::time_point s

Tags: c++, duration, c++-chrono

Why won't the following function compile, with the error

```
cannot convert from 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::duration<double,std::nano>>' to 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::steady_clock::duration>'
```

---

```
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point TimePoint;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<86400>> JulianDays;

TimePoint JulianDaysToUTC(const JulianDays& days)
{
    static const JulianDays EquivalentJulianYearInDays(2451545.0);
    static const JulianDays LeapSecondCorrection(0.0008);
    static const TimePoint CorrectedEpoch = TimePoint() - EquivalentJulianYearInDays + LeapSecondCorrection;
    return CorrectedEpoch + days;
}
```

Note: `TimePoint()` was substituted for a function returning a `TimePoint`, but that return value is not / should not be relevant.

Modifying it to use an integer duration allows it to compile, but I lose the fractional day portion, which is undesired.

```
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point TimePoint;
typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::ratio<86400>> Days;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<86400>> JulianDays;

TimePoint JulianDaysToUTC(const JulianDays& days)
{
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    static const JulianDays EquivalentJulianYearInDays(2451545.0);
    static const JulianDays LeapSecondCorrection(0.0008);
    static const TimePoint CorrectedEpoch = TimePoint() - duration_cast<Days>(EquivalentJulianYearInDays) + duration_cast<Days>(LeapSecondCorrection);
    return CorrectedEpoch + duration_cast<Days>(days);
}
```

Comment: FYI: The high-resolution-clock's epoch is frequently not fixed. It may differ on different executions of the same program.

Comment: I believe for the application that this will be used, differences between different executions won't matter, so long as within the same execution it is the same. Not entirely sure, but I'll ask next week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<chrono>` library is designed so that truncation error won't happen implicitly.  This is because truncation error can easily happen and often results in an accidental loss of information.

The error message:

> cannot convert from `time_point<steady_clock, duration<double,std::nano>>`
>   to `time_point<steady_clock, steady_clock::duration>`

is saying that an implicit conversion from fractional nanoseconds (double-based) to whole nanoseconds (integral-based) has been attempted but is not allowed.  It turns out that every `steady_clock::duration` happens to be nanoseconds, though that is not specified.

If truncation is what you desire (as in this case), one can use `duration_cast` or `time_point_cast` to truncate towards zero.  In C++17, `floor`, `ceil` and `round` truncation modes are added.

Here is the most straight-forward way to perform the truncation casts that the library is refusing to do implicitly:

```
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point TimePoint;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<86400>> JulianDays;

TimePoint JulianDaysToUTC(const JulianDays& days)
{
    static const JulianDays EquivalentJulianYearInDays(2451545.0);
    static const JulianDays LeapSecondCorrection(0.0008);
    static const TimePoint CorrectedEpoch =
        std::chrono::time_point_cast<TimePoint::duration>(
            TimePoint() - EquivalentJulianYearInDays + LeapSecondCorrection);
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<TimePoint::duration>(CorrectedEpoch + days);
}
```

The first cast is necessary because the expression `TimePoint() - EquivalentJulianYearInDays + LeapSecondCorrection` has type `time_point<high_resolution_clock, duration<double, nano>>` (floating point nanoseconds time_point), and the destination type is a integral-based nanoseconds time_point.  Ditto for the second conversion.

`auto` could be used to clean this code up a little, and avoid one of the conversions:

```
#include <chrono>

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point TimePoint;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<86400>> JulianDays;

TimePoint JulianDaysToUTC(const JulianDays& days)
{
    static const JulianDays EquivalentJulianYearInDays(2451545.0);
    static const JulianDays LeapSecondCorrection(0.0008);
    static const auto CorrectedEpoch = TimePoint() -
                                       EquivalentJulianYearInDays + LeapSecondCorrection;
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<TimePoint::duration>(CorrectedEpoch + days);
}
```

Now `CorrectedEpoch` is a double-based nanosecond time_point, but that detail is not really important to your algorithm.

---

Also, Nicol Bolas's comment about the suspicious use of `high_resolution_clock` is warranted.  Your code may work if you never mix a `TimePoint` with a `high_resolution_clock::time_point` that came from `high_resolution_clock::now()`.  However you would be safer to just create your own custom clock with a documented 2000-01-01 12:00:00 UTC epoch.  Then any accidental mixing would be caught at compile time.